# ejabberd login error with interface

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, google-ajax-libraries

I am used jaxl library to connect to my server openfire. I am get success all to login and sendMessage by used command line. Now i want to make a interface for loin and pass the JID and Password. the result is connected session but it's can't direct to home page. It's have problem around :
`$client->start(array(
            '--with-debug-shell' => true
            '--with-Unix-sock' => true
        ));`
line ! please help me to give some idea. how to fix it.

Comment: What kind of interface are you trying to build? I understand input to this interface will be Jabber Id and password. Do you want to pre-bind a Bosh session with provided credentials? What exact problem or errors are you getting?

Comment: i am run success in command line (login; online; getContact; chat) but i want to make interface for user easy to use. as $jid= $_POST['itxt_name']; $pass= $_POST['ipass_pass']; and pass it to sever (it's example for login) show that jaxl 1> jaxl 2> jaxl 3> jaxl 4> jaxl 5> jaxl 6> jaxl 7> jaxl 8> jaxl 9> jaxl 10> jaxl 11> jaxl 12> jaxl 13> jaxl 14> jaxl 15> jaxl 16> jaxl 17[........] jaxl 306> and we see user online in our server already but not pass to home page.